# OpenCV python cv2.Canny function's output Mat object doesn't have channel information

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to add 2 different Mat objects in python.
Both Mat objects are binary images (CV_8U). But because the Matrices don't have the same size, I get an error when adding them.

I generate one of the Mat objects using numpy with the proper value for the channels, like this:

`diagonal = np.zeros((height,width,1))
cv2.line(diagonal,(0,0),(height,width), (255))`

The other Mat object comes from cv2.Canny:

```
canny_edge = cv2.Canny(input_image, min_thr, max_thr)
```

Addition code:
`final = cv2.addWeighted(canny_edge,1.0,diagonal,1.0,0)`

I get the following error when I try to add the 2 Mat objects:
`error: (-5) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function cv::arithm_op`

I also tried removing the channels value from the numpy generated matrix, but I got the same error.

So I tried to print the channels, but I got this:

`height, weight, channels = canny_edge.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

EDIT: I am sorry but the answer posted by Miki doesn't help me. The Mat object generated by cv2.Canny doesn't have channel information. I know it is a binary image, but opencv gets confused when it tries to add this Mat object's matrix with a Mat object which does have channel information.

Comment: @Miki , I have updated the question to show what the issue is in more detail. The question you have tagged doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Can't you just add a singleton dimension to `canny_edge`?

Comment: @Miki thanks for the reply. Yes, I tried that. But the addition never terminates. It seems like it gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: @Miki Sorry. Please ignore my last comment. I thought I tried it but I can't find context. Could you please tell me how do I add a singleton dimension to the Mat object which is output of cv2.Canny?

Comment: I will post the answer here for others as the question is marked duplicate and I am not getting an answer button.
Basically, use the `canny_edge` Mat object and convert it to a numpy array using:
`canny_edge_nparr = np.asarray(canny_edge)`
And then we can add a dimension to it:
`canny_edge_nparr = np.expand_dims(canny_edge_nparr, axis=2)`
Now the shape represents (height, width, channels)
Now use numpy addition to add the arrays:
`final = np.add(canny_edge_nparr, diagonal)`

Comment: Now you can post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, use the canny_edge Mat object and convert it to a numpy array using:

`canny_edge_nparr = np.asarray(canny_edge)`

And then we can add a dimension to it (as the cv2.Canny outputs a Mat object of shape: (height, width) ):

`canny_edge_nparr = np.expand_dims(canny_edge_nparr, axis=2)`

Now the shape represents (height, width, channels). Now use numpy addition to add the arrays:

`final = np.add(canny_edge_nparr, diagonal)`